# Create a list from matrix in R

Tags: r

I have two lists `v` and `w` and I would like to create again a list `z` from matrix `M` . How can I do this in R?

```
    v = list(a = c(1, 5), b = 2, c= 3)
    w = list( a= c(2, 10), b = 4, c = 6)
    M  =  as.matrix(unlist( v) * unlist(w))
    > M
        [,1]
    a1    2
    a2   50
    b     8
    c    18
    z = list(a = c(2, 50), b = 8, c = 18)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
mapply(`*`, v, w)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want `z <- lapply(1:length(v), function(i) v[[i]]*w[[i]])`? Add `names(z) <- names(v)` to keep the names.